# scrapy different spider for different type item

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, scrapy

I think the framework of [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) might be a little inflexible. And I can't find good solution for my issue.

Here's the issue I'm facing now.

There's a website, let's say, to be, `http://example.com/`. I want to scrap some information from it.

It has many items which are urls in form of `http://example.com/item/([0-9]+)`, for now I **have** the list of the valid `([0-9]+)` which has about **3 million** index ids, it might seems to be a simple mission to complete the whole webpage scrapping work.

**But**, the structure of this mission is like this:

- there are many data of the item on the page of `/item/`. I want these information, this is simple to achieve.
- there are links refer to the entity related to the item, for example `item owner` with link path `/owner/`, or `the collections the item belongs` with link path `/collection/` and so on. I want all the **unique** information of these entities, which is hard to achieve. They shouldn't be the nested item of `item` or scrapped by single spider because of the reason below:

  - **single** `owner` have `[1-n]` items.
  - **single** item  have `[1-n]` `owners`.
  - same as `collection` with item.
- there are links refer to other entity related to the item, for example, `comment` with link path `/comment/` or `user` who like it with link path `/user/`. Obviously, it's wise to split `comment` or `user` information away from `item` and use **key or index** to refer to entity. This is hard to achieve by single spider.

So, I prefer to start a spider to handle the list of `http://example.com/item/([0-9]+)`, and use other type of spiders to handle with `item owner`, `collection`, `comment`, and `user` respectively.

**But**, the problem is I don't have the list of `item owner`, `collection`, `comment`, and `user`. I could go through all of these entities only by iterate the webpage of `http://example.com/item/([0-9]+)`.

I have googled a lot but found no solution to fit my issue. Please feel free to give your opinion out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's pseudo code for `ItemSpider`.

```
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
import redis
class ItemSpider(RedisSpider):
    name = 'item'
    def parse(self, response):
        # process to get item info.
        r = redis.Redis(...)
        r.lpush('user:start_urls', user_link)
        return ...
```

Here's pseudo code for `UserSpider`.

```
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
class UserSpider(RedisSpider):
    name = 'user'
    def parse(self, response):
        # process to get user info.
        return ...
```

And then add your item urls into `item:start_urls` list in redis.

Finally,

```
scrapy crawl item
scrapy crawl user
```

More advanced concepts such as avoiding duplicated items should be considered in advance. At least the solution described above have splitted the schedule of `ItemSpider` and `UserSpider` away.

I come into this solution because of the help from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/yI3bpbsWeP0), thanks @lnxpgn.

Can anyone provide better solution? Or provide better solution for avoiding duplicated crawling?

Answer (score 1):

Most of your requirements seem to fit scrapy very well. You've already said you can scrape the list of items simply which is a good start. I think you're saying that each item has links to owner, comment, user. In this case you get the URL using response.xpath and then `yield Request(URL, callback=parse_owner)` as an example. You will want to link the different scraped data together, in which case you can add `meta={'id': identifier}` to the Request(). As @kotrfa said, dumping to a database may be best as this sounds like there is some cross-linking of data.

That's as far as I can go given the information you provided. More information would make the picture clearer for us.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I know the procedure you described. I do think this could finish what I request basically. If there exist any better solution I will choose that. The reason I expect better solution is that there a few problems with this approach. [1] duplicated page crawls and database record.(imagine two worker is working on two items that has the same owner simultaneously). [2] work schedule (In your solution, work for `owner`,`user` and so on is not splitted from `item`, this might involve some db locks which could be avoided by better modularity). Anyway, your procedure does works.

Comment: Scrapy will only visit a page once by default, and it can cache pages locally if multiple visits to a page are necessary. In settings.py, set `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True`. If you could give us some examples you might get more help. If my answer has helped don't forget to accept/upvote it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your information. I'm not familiar with this details. Ok, I think I've get better solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/yI3bpbsWeP0). I've roughly implement it quickly. For example, just write `ItemSpider` and `UserSpider`, integrating `redis` with `scrapy-redis`. Add the **3M** urls to the `start_urls` of `ItemSpider` in the redis, and when `ItemSpider` found a link of user to crawl, add its url to the `start_urls` of `UserSpider` in the redis. And after two spiders code finished, start two spiders respectively. Then job done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are not looking for *multidomain* crawler because you are basically scrapping one domain, right? You don't even need to follow many different and unpredictable links, since you already know what you want to look for. Is this correct?

For this purpose I would recommend to use rather `selenium` (maybe with BeautifulSoup). `selenium` is quite lightweight, can run headless with PhantomJS and if you know structure of the page being scrapped, you can put much more logic and control compared to Scrappy (well, definitely more easily).

I don't see the structure and types of final data, but it seems they are somewhat hierarchical and there are relationships between them. I would store data in dict with lists even when they are not unique and then dump them to e.g. MongoDB (super easy with pymongo, basically 3 commands to create connection and then one to put it into database). After collecting this I would care about relationships, filtering and stuff. It's usually much easier later on (with tools for this purpose such as `pandas`) then during the scrapping.

For your particular case I would do a for loop over the range you wish to scrap (3M) and in every step you'll run function for access that URL, if not 404, then scrap info, then scrap owners, then scrap category... These should be separate functions, selectors will vary based on the structure, use proper CSS or XPATH as much as possible, otherwise you can use `find_elements` and then filter them based on the text or href (e.g. `/owner/` in `href` of all `a`).

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I'd rather not choose `selenium` or `requests` with `BeautifulSoup`, since there might be some further problems that I haven't mentioned in my post such as `performance`, `scheduler`, `multiple proxies`, `scrap rate` and so on, since these problems is not related directly with the issue I post. But use handmade scripts might not be a good choice for my desire. Thank you all the same.